How to Fix Firebase Deploy Unexpected Error Occured?
firebase deploy --only hosting

=== Deploying to 'PROJECT'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[PROJECT]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[PROJECT]: found 55 files in public
-
Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
|  hosting: hashing files [41/55] (74%)

When we follow the Hosting steps provided by the Firebase with command "firebase deploy", we also get the error:

Error: If you'd like to provision a CloudSQL Postgres instance on the
Firebase Data Connect no-cost trial:

Please upgrade to the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan. Visit the following page:
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/PROJECT/usage/details
Run firebase init dataconnect again to configure the Cloud SQL instance.
Run firebase deploy --only dataconnect to deploy your Data Connect service.


But we do not use Data Connect.
How can we solve this issue?
Thanks!
firebase deploy --only hosting
And
firebase deploy

If you're getting an error message that isn't helpful, you should reach out to Firebase support directly.  There's not enough information in your question that someone here can use to reproduce the issue.
